# MongoDB $ifNull empty array still adding data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, aggregation

I have 2 collections, users and tracks. When I fetch the user profile I want to get his tracks.
The user object has `tracks` as an array of track IDs, and the second collection is of the tracks.

Now I am running this code below:

```
users
    .aggregate([
      {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId(userId) },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "tracks",
          localField: "tracks",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "tracks",
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$tracks",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $group: {
          _id: ObjectId(userId),
          username: { $first: "$username" },
          profileImg: { $first: "$profileImg" },
          socialLinks: { $first: "$socialLinks" },
          tracks: {
            $push: {
              _id: "$tracks._id",
              name: "$tracks.name",
              categoryId: "$tracks.categoryId",
              links: "$tracks.links",
              mediaId: isLogged ? "$tracks.mediaId" : null,
              thumbnailId: "$tracks.thumbnailId",
              views: { $size: { $ifNull: ["$tracks.views", []] } },
              downloads: { $size: { $ifNull: ["$tracks.downloads", []] } },
              uploadedDate: "$tracks.uploadedDate",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ])
```

In case the user does not have tracks or there are no tracks, the `$ifNull` statement returns an object only with these fields so it looks like that:

```
user: {
    // user data
    tracks: [{ views: 0, downloads: 0, mediaId: null }]
}
```

There are no tracks found so `"tracks.views"` cannot be read so I added the $ifNull statement, how can I avoid it from returning an empty data? also, the API call knows whether the user is logged or not (`isLogged`), I set the `mediaId` to `null`.
If there are no tracks found, why does the code still add these 3 fields only? no tracks to go through them...

Edit:
Any track has `downloads` and `views` containing user IDs whom downloaded / viewed the track, the track looks like that

```
{
    "name": "New Track #2227",
    "categoryId": "61695d57893f048528d049e5",
    "links": {
        "youtube": "https://www.youtube.com",
        "soundcloud": null,
        "spotify": null
    },
    "_id": "616c90651ab67bbd0b0a1172",
    "creatorId": "61695b5986ed44e5c1e1d29d",
    "mediaId": "616c90651ab67bbd0b0a1171",
    "thumbnailId": "616c90651ab67bbd0b0a1170",
    "plays": [],
    "status": "pending",
    "downloads": [],
    "uploadedDate": 1634504805
}
```

When the fetched user doesn't have any track post yet, I receive an array with one object that contains the fields mentioned above.

What I expect to get when the user has no tracks is an empty array, as you can see the response above, the track object isn't full and contains only the conditional keys with zero value and null.
Bottom line I want the length of `views` and `downloads` only if there is a track or more, also for the `mediaId` which I want to hide it in case the user isn't logged. If there are no tracks I don't understand why it returns these 3 fields

expected result when the user has one track or more

```
user: {
  // user data
  tracks: [
    {
      name: "New Track #2227",
      categoryId: "61695d57893f048528d049e5",
      links: {
        youtube: "https://www.youtube.com",
        soundcloud: null,
        spotify: null,
      },
      _id: "616c90651ab67bbd0b0a1172",
      creatorId: "61695b5986ed44e5c1e1d29d",
      mediaId: "616c90651ab67bbd0b0a1171",
      thumbnailId: "616c90651ab67bbd0b0a1170",
      plays: 0,
      status: "pending",
      downloads: 0,
      uploadedDate: 1634504805,
    },
  ];
}
```

expected result when the user has no tracks

```
user: {
  // user data
  tracks: [];
}
```

Comment: what is the desired output,can you add a sample? if empty data field to be missing? check `$$REMOVE` also maybe it can help you

Comment: @Takis_ Hi again! in case the user doesn't have tracks posted, I expect to get an empty array for the downloads / views, right now it sends these 3 fields. it should be the entire track (if found) or nothing at all...

Comment: Not clear what you like to get, perhaps try `views: { $ifNull: ["$tracks.views", []] } ` or `views: { $ifNull: ["$tracks.views", "$$REMOVE"] }`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit updated the question, tried `"$$REMOVE"` instead of `[]` and it throws this error `The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing`

Comment: Providing some sample input data is a good starting point. Please also provide expected sample output data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit https://mongoplayground.net/p/bfAAKg-cPev you can see here, `tracks` db is empty but the response adds the `views` and `downloads` with 0, there is no track at all.. `user.tracks` should be an empty array. the `mediaId` is also by condition if the user is logged or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append this stage to your pipeline:

```
{
  $set: {
    tracks: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$tracks",
        cond: { $ne: [ { $type: "$$this._id" }, "missing" ] } 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You got me! Thanks, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also modify your query to look something like this: (check out a [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V4aKUfpS34W))

This query uses a conditional push via `$cond` coupled with the `$and` operator to search for more than one condition. If `tracks.downloads` or `tracks.plays` are not greater than 0, we use the [`$$REMOVE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#mongodb-variable-variable.REMOVE) variable (which just ignores that document and returns an empty array, like you are looking for).

### Query

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("616c80793235ab5cc26dbaff")
    },
    
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tracks",
      localField: "tracks",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "tracks"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$tracks",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: ObjectId("616c80793235ab5cc26dbaff"),
      username: {
        $first: "$username"
      },
      profileImg: {
        $first: "$profileImg"
      },
      socialLinks: {
        $first: "$socialLinks"
      },
      tracks: {
        $push: {
          // "IF" plays and downloads > 0
          $cond: [
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$tracks.plays",
                    0
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gt: [
                    "$tracks.downloads",
                    0
                  ]
                },
                
              ]
            },
            // "THEN" return document
            {
              _id: "$tracks._id",
              name: "$tracks.name",
              categoryId: "$tracks.categoryId",
              links: "$tracks.links",
              mediaId: "$tracks.mediaId",
              thumbnailId: "$tracks.thumbnailId",
              plays2: {},
              plays: "$tracks.plays",
              downloads: "$tracks.downloads",
              uploadedDate: "$tracks.uploadedDate"
            },
            // "ELSE" remove
            "$$REMOVE"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: i can see there is a condition of `$and` for the plays and downloads > 0, what if there is a track of that user that has 0 downloads/plays? or a track that has 1+ downloads and 0 views (and vice versa)?

Comment: I changed the condition to `$ifNull: ["$tracks._id", false]` and it works :) only if there is an ID, so whether plays/downloads are 0 or something else it will be fine as long as the track exists https://mongoplayground.net/p/xtvrczmOzdk